# update nested value in javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, object

This is an odd question, but I hope someone can help me out.

I have a JS object (it's actually JSON string which is then converted back and object.).

```
{
  "legs": [{
    "pods": [{
      "11": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "tesla",
        "text": "tesla model2",
        "battery": "60"
      },
      "21": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "porsche",
        "text": "porsche electric",
        "battery": "100"
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

So in my javascript I'll call a specific item... say, legs.pods[11].name

I pass that into a function like editThisField(legs.pods[11].name);

On that function editThisField(whichDataElement){.....} I'll show a modal box where the user can provide new text for the name value... what I would like is to have the whichDataElement updated to the new text such that which ever object variable I pass into that field, is updated in the legs object... I'm not sure if I'm explaining this very well, but I can't think where to start looking at a good approach to this.

Essentially I'm making a text area where I paste in the JSON, and the system allows me to edit the JSON object via modal popups. So the modal appears and dynamically shows a form based on the data in the specific sub object. When you fill in the form, the original JSON is updated... thoughts?

Not really working as I need... Maybe this helps clarify:

```
var mything = {
    subthing: {
        thisthing: "here"
    }
}

var edit = mything.subthing.thisthing;
edit = "Changed";
console.log(mything); // then the listthing value should be changed.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `legs.pods[11].name` is invalid because `pods` is an array containing a single object - you’d need to do `legs.pods[0]['11'].name` or similar

Comment: Not really working as I need... Maybe this helps clarify:

    var mything = {
     subthing: {
      thisthing: "here"
     }
    }

   var edit = mything.subthing.thisthing;
   edit = "Changed";
   console.log(mything); // then the listthing value should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're on the right track. If you pass in an **object** to your `editThisField` function you can change it's contents, but in your example you are passing in a primitive (which won't work as it's passed by value).

Another option... since you're loading a modal I assume you know what attribute you want to change so you can just specify the object keys or array indices dynamically. See example here https://jsfiddle.net/jroden1f/. Note, I changed your data model slightly as I wasn't sure why you had legs and pods as arrays and it made the example easier if I just made them objects.